Livewire wired checkbox has wrong checked state with nested values
When nested boolean property values (e.g. nested.value) of a Livewire component change, checkboxes do not change their checked state.
Here is a wirebox with the scenario: https://wirebox.app/b/x58lv
Initial state is correct. When a model is loaded, the checked states do not change.
The checkboxes with not nested values work.
This occurs for example when I use Livewire Form Objects.
No problem with not nested values.
<?php
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\BoolModel;

class Simple extends Component
{
    public $bools = [
        'one' => true,
        'two' => false,
    ];

    public string $name = 'none';

    public bool $one = true;
    public bool $two = false;
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.simple');
    }

    public function load($id)
    {
        $model = BoolModel::find($id);
        
        $this->name = $model->name;
        
        $this->bools = [
            'one' => $model->one,
            'two' => $model->two,
        ];
        
        $this->one = $model->one;
        $this->two = $model->two;
    }
}

<div>
    <h1 class="text-white">{{ $name }}</h1>
    <div class="flex w-full h-full items-center justify-center text-gray-300 px-16">
        <div class="text-light me-3">Array:</div> 
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.blur="bools.one" /><span class="mx-2"> :: {{$bools['one'] ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.blur="bools.two" /><span class="mx-2"> :: {{$bools['two'] ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex w-full h-full items-center justify-center text-gray-300 px-16">
        <div class="text-light me-3">single:</div> 
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.blur="one" /><span class="mx-2"> :: {{$one ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" wire:model.blur="two" /><span class="mx-2"> :: {{$two ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>
    </div>
        <div>
    <button class="bg-white" role="button" wire:click="load(1)">load 1</button>
    <button class="bg-white" role="button" wire:click="load(2)">load 2</button>
        </div>
</div>



Laravel Sushi (which you are using in your Wirebox example) converts booleans to integers by default as many DBMS engines do
To verify this behaviour you can replace the ternary operators in the <span> tags of the view with var_export() which output the real values of the variables:
<!--<span class="mx-2"> :: {{$bools['one'] ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>-->
<span class="mx-2"> :: {{var_export($bools['one'], true)}}</span>

<!--<span class="mx-2"> :: {{$bools['two'] ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>-->
<span class="mx-2"> :: {{var_export($bools['two'], true)}}</span>

<!--<span class="mx-2"> :: {{$one ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>-->
<span class="mx-2"> :: {{var_export($one, true)}}</span>

<!--<span class="mx-2"> :: {{$two ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>-->
<span class="mx-2"> :: {{var_export($two, true)}}</span>

When you assign the integer to non-array properties that are defined as bools in your class, e.g.: public bool $one = true;, an implicit cast is performed and the numeric values are converted to booleans.
On the other hand this conversion is not performed automatically when these values are assigned to the items of the associative array
When Livewire assigns values ​​to checkboxes it evidently checks the boolean values ​​strictly and if it receives non-boolean values ​​(such as 0 or 1) it cannot set the checks correctly
Solution:
To obtain the correct behaviour for the values which are elements of an associative array you can add casts in your model:
protected $casts = [
    'one' => 'boolean',
    'two' => 'boolean'
];

in this way the properties of the model will contain boolean values and the arrays will receive booleans too

this is actually very unexpected as it is not documented. I do not use Laravel Sushi, only in the wirebox, but the cast solves the problem in my project as well, there I use regular Models and a Livewire Form Object. I wonder why not more people noticed this ...

Many DBMS manage the boolean as integers, I suppose that Laravel Sushi is structured to be coherent with this behaviour

Please try it yourself and let me know if you have any questions.
https://wirebox.app/b/xgddk

That Box is private. You habe to make it public if you want to share it. Thanks

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@ChristianWagner I have made it public,

Answers should not relay on external resources - Please [edit] the answer and add the relevant parts inside - Furthermore, link- and code-only answers are not good answers. Please explain what you changed to address the issue - [answer]
